# How do I interpret this zero eigenvector?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a matrix \begin{bmatrix}3&0\\3&4\end{bmatrix}

Which has the eigenvalues $3$ and $4$. My question involves finding the eigenvector with $\lambda  = 4$. So through subtracting 4 identity matrix copies and row reducing the output I have obtained the matrix:

\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&0&0\\\end{bmatrix}

Wouldn't this imply the eigenvector being the zero vector? I thought this was not allowed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your augmented matrix means that the eigenvector $(x,y)$ with eigenvalue $4$ satisfies $$\cases{1x+0y=0\\0x+0y=0}$$

Comment: Doesn't it imply $x = 0$, and as such it is the zero vector?

Comment: Yes $x=0$ but $y$ is free.

Comment: @Synlar $x=0$, yes. But the only thing we're told about $y$ is that $0y=0$. What numbers satisfy this?

Comment: Struggling to come out with any eigenvector for this. It is basic linear algebra, and the question requests an answer in the form $(x, y)$. What would I put in that? And for that question - $y$ can be anything. I am so confused!

Comment: @Synlar Exactly! $y$ can be anything. That means that $(0,1)$ is an eigenvector. So are $(0,5)$, $(0,\pi)$ and $(0,954\,367\,324)$. Eigenvectors for one specific eigenvalue are never unique, but constitute a full vector space.

Comment: (cont.) when taken together with the zero vector. (Damn technicalities.)